# WHERE NOT EXISTS in PostgreSQL gives syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

When trying to use the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause to prevent adding a row with a duplicate value in the column `age`, I get the error `syntax error at or near "WHERE"`.

Why did it throw a syntax error? I'm using Postgresql 9.1.

**SQL**

```
INSERT INTO live.users ("website", "age") 
values ('abc', '123')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT age FROM live.users WHERE age = 123);
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 6: WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT age FROM live.users W...
```

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicate values in a column, it would be better to add a `unique constraint`to that column.  (ALTER TABLE live.users ADD CONSTRAINT age_unique UNIQUE(age) )

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do instead:

```
INSERT INTO live.users ("website", "age") 
SELECT 'abc', 123
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT age FROM live.users WHERE age = 123);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO live.users ("website", "age") 
select 'abc', '123'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT age FROM live.users WHERE age = 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you asked for v9.1 but it's been 4 yrs since and now, starting from [PostgreSQL v9.5 - INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) gives you `ON CONFLICT … DO NOTHING` option:

```
INSERT INTO live.users("website", "age") VALUES('abc', '123') ON CONFLICT ("age") DO NOTHING
```

Worth noting **this requires respective constraint** set up on the target table - but in most cases, I imagine you would have it anyway. Otherwise you'll get:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered some issues in using `WHERE field NOT EXISTS` in PLPGSQL. Instead what worked well was `WHERE field NOT IN`,  I received no function errors after using that.