# insert unique values to postgresql

Tags: sql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.3

iam create a table using below command in postgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
    id serial primary key,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int NOT NULL,
    unique (col1, col2)
);
```

then am execute 2 insert statements.

1. `insert into someTable (col1,col2) values(1,11),(1,12);`

   its working
2. `insert into someTable (col1,col2) values(1,13),(1,14),(1,11);`

   got error (key(col1,col2)=(1,11) is already exist.

But i need to avoid only duplicate pairs. How it will be possible ?

iam try this with

PostgreSQL 9.5.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit and PostgreSQL 9.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit

but i got error

i need ot put like this after executing two statements.

```
(1,11),(1,12),(1,13),(1,14)
```

Comment: The second insert tries to insert the values `(1,11)` which you have already inserted with the first statement. And as you have defined `col1, col2` to be unique, you can't insert the same tuple twice.

Comment: is it possible to insert all other values( avoid duplicate pairs).?

Comment: Not with Postgres 9.1, you can do that with Postgres 9.5

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1009584/330315 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109061/330315 for possible solutions with older Postgres versions. Note that 9.1 is going to be out of support in 8 months so you should plan an upgrade anyway

Comment: iam using PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit. thanks for valluable comments

Comment: So shouldn't this question be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert multiple rows where not exists PostgresQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769157/insert-multiple-rows-where-not-exists-postgresql)

Comment: am upgrade my postgresql version to 9.5 . but still got error..

Comment: Well, with Postgres 9.5 you need to use the new `insert ... on conflict ()` syntax

Comment: ho, its working fine. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into someTable(col1, col2) 
    select col1, col2
    from (select 1 as col1, 13 as col2 union all
          select 1, 14 union all
          select 1, 11
         ) t
    where not exists (select 1
                      from someTable st
                      where st.col1 = t.col1 and st.col2 = t.col2
                     );
```

That is, filter the values out before the `insert`.

EDIT:

As a-horse-with-no-name points out, you can also write this as:

```
insert into someTable(col1, col2) 
    select col1, col2
    from (values (1, 13), (1, 14), (1, 11)
         ) as t(col1, col2)
    where not exists (select 1
                      from someTable st
                      where st.col1 = t.col1 and st.col2 = t.col2
                     );
```

I tend to use the `union all` approach because not all databases support this use of the `values()` statement.

Comment: No need for the verbose `select` in the derived table. You can use `values (1,13), (1,14)` directly there

Comment: i got error from above syntax  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 2:     from (values (1, 13), (1, 14), (1, 11)

Comment: @AbdulManaf . . . Somehow the `select` was missing before the `from`.

Answer (score 3):

using postgresql 9.5 (latest release)

use query like this

> ```
> insert into someTable (col1,col2) values(1,13),(1,14),(1,11) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
> ```

it will avoid duplication without any extra line of code.