# Do nothing on foreign key violation in SQL insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a migration program, I execute an insert query to table_1 which is defined like this :

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
    col1 character varying(4)  COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    col2 character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    col3 character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    col4 character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    col5 date NOT NULL,
    col6 date NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT table_1_pkey 
        PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6),

    CONSTRAINT table_2_fkey FOREIGN KEY (col4)
        REFERENCES table_2 (col1) MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT table_3_fkey FOREIGN KEY (col3)
        REFERENCES table_3(col1) MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            NOT VALID
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Now when I try to insert to this table, I get this error :

> Error in transaction  error: insert or update on table "table_1" violates foreign key constraint "table_2_fkey"

I tried to do an insert query in this form :

```
INSERT INTO table_1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) 
VALUES 
(col1_value1, col2_value1, col3_value1, col4_value1, col5_value1, col6_value1),
(col1_value2, col2_value2, col3_value2, col4_value2, col5_value2, col6_value2),
(col1_value3, col2_value3, col3_value3, col4_value3, col5_value3, col6_value3)
ON CONFLICT (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) DO NOTHING;
```

Is there a way to prevent violation of the foreign key constraint (skip them)?

Something like `ON VIOLATION DO NOTHING`.

**Note**: it doesn't violate the second foreign key constraint because I fill the data in this table (table_2) with the rows I try to fill into table_1 (for normalization). table_2 is a table that existed earlier and I fill the rows there in another program, so there might be missing data there, and I want to skip inserting the rows to table_1 that doesn't match the foreign key to table_2.

Using PostgreSQL 10.16, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a variation of a query from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769231/14254771). Thanks to [@_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-namepostgresql#:%7E:text=at%2022%3A28-,a_horse_with_no_name,-449k80)

This is the query that worked for me :

```
with data_table(col1, col2, col3, col4,
                col5, col6) as (
    values
        ('value1','','1','num1','1900-01-01'::date, '9999-12-31'::date),
        ('value2','','1','num2','1900-01-01'::date, '9999-12-31'::date)   
)
insert into table_1(col1, col2, col3,
                    col4, col5, col6)
select d.col1, d.col2, d.col3, d.col4,
       d.col5, d.col6
from data_table d
where exists (select 1
              from table_2 t2
              where t2.col1 = d.col4)
on conflict(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) do nothing;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no, "Do Nothing" option for violating constraints.  You can create a dummy field in your table_2 such that when the value is unavailable to be matched in the parent table it has something to reference in table_2 (a placeholder value of sorts).

Alternatively, you can remove the foreign key constraint by using a mapping table instead.  This way, you can decide if the map table should have a new record inserted.  This is unlikely to be best way to meet your design goals.

```
table_1
    id
    ...  other data fields ...

table_2
    id
    ...  other data fields ...

map_table
    id
    table1_id (FK)
    table2_id (FK)
```

Comment: I would go for the the second solution, the problem is that I don't decide how the design will be in my case. For the first solution I cannot use a placeholder when a value is unavailable because it brings me back to the question : how do I tell sql to do something \ take some value when a violation happens ?

Comment: There is no violation in the second case.  You are doing two inserts, insert into table_1 and then if there is a value in table_2 then you can insert into map_table.  This would have to be a business logic decision as opposed to a sql statement (imo)

Comment: I definitely agree with you that the second approach would have solved it. Although, it doesn't meet my needs. For the first solution, how do I check in the insert query if the value exists in table_2 and if not take a placeholder instead ? Also, this is not the solution I'm looking for, I want to skip and not insert a row to table_1 if the value doesn't exist in table_2.