# Insert results from select query, which is already changed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to run this query:

```
INSERT INTO contacts_fields (
  contact_id, field_name, numeric_value
)
select distinct      
  c.id, 
  'storeId', 
  1
from 
  contacts c 
  inner join contacts_devices cd on cd.contact_id = c.id 
  and c.id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
      contact_id 
    FROM 
      contacts_fields
  )
group by 
  c.id
```

But I am getting an error:

```
SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: insert or update on table "contact_fields" violates foreign key constraint "contacts_fields_fkey"
Detail: Key (contact_id)=(2425542) is not present in table "contacts".
```

This is propably because `contacts` table is changing all the time, any maybe I can't insert value with id = `2425542`, becasuse it was deleted between `select` and `insert` query. What can I do with this?

Comment: [on conflict do nothing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) is your friend.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I tried, but it says, that it is not designed for `fk` constraints, but `unique` constraints

Comment: I see. You may have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530673/do-nothing-on-foreign-key-violation-in-sql-insert-query) then.